# where can I find /packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons.js

Tags: meteor

when I run my meteor application I get this error

```
   => Errors prevented startup:
While computing assigned variables:

   /packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons.js: Unexpected token (164:0)

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

where can I find this path:

```
 /packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons.js
```

I found login_buttons.js through this path :

```
C:\Users\connect\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\accounts-ui-unstyled\1.3.0\web.browser
```

and

```
C:\Users\connect\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\accounts-ui-unstyled\1.3.0\web.cordova
```

although these two paths are not the same as mentioned in the error message

Comment: Did you install the accounts-ui package? `meteor add accounts-ui`. Also try doing an `npm install` to resolve dependencies.

Comment: @MichelFloyd  yes I did install the package , I also ran the npm install command and still had the same error